# INSERT trigger not SELECTing rows

Tags: sql-server-2012, trigger, database-mail

I'm working with a application and I have no control over the application source code, only SQL.

The entire process is this:

1. Row inserted via an application
2. Vendor trigger fires and calls an SP to insert the new row into my table. This new row is returned when I do a SELECT
3. I have an INSERT trigger on my table that selects the row and executes sp_send_dbmail to email the row just inserted (and will then truncate my table when live)

The issue is that I get the email (so the INSERT is picked up and the trigger executes) but it's blank.

If I then INSERT a second row, the trigger fires and I get an email containing the first row inserted.

My trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SendEmail_INS]
ON [dbo].[tbl_UNIT_INS]
FOR INSERT
-- AFTER INSERT
AS

DECLARE @thequery NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @thequery =
    'SET NOCOUNT ON
     SELECT  contract,
         cont_line,
         site_ref,
         comp_id,
         cont_line as cont_line2,
         item,
         qty,
         ser_num,
         cust_num,
         description,
         unit_stat_code
    FROM tbl_UNIT_INS'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @query_result_header = 0,
     @exclude_query_output = 1,
     @profile_name = 'Outbound',
     @recipients = 'me@email.com,
     @query = @thequery,
     @subject = 'New Item Inserted'
```

I've tried using AFTER INSERT as well - same result.

It seems the trigger is firing before the row is inserted but the fact I get an email means the insert has happened so the insert has completed?

SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Not sure if it's actually part of your query but you're missing an end quote after the @recipients email address.

Comment: Don't you need delimiters when using multiple statements in `@query`?

Comment: What happens if a rollback needs to occur and you have already sent the email?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have better luck pulling from `inserted` instead of from the base table (and of course fixing the typo that should have prevented compilation), but you should also consider not using e-mail from a trigger at all.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SendEmail_INS]
ON [dbo].[tbl_UNIT_INS]
FOR INSERT -- AFTER INSERT is the exact same thing as FOR INSERT.
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @query_result_header = 0,
     @exclude_query_output = 1,
     @profile_name = 'Outbound',
     @recipients = 'me@email.com', -- fixed missing quote here
     @query = N'SELECT * FROM inserted;',
     @subject = 'New Item Inserted';
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've taken Aaron's suggestion and moved the `sp_send_dbmail` functionality into a SP and called it from trigger. All working. Thanks

Comment: you are still e-mailing from the trigger, even if it's one layer removed.  I think Aaron was trying to convince you to accomplish your task a different way.